# QuickBooks SDK CustomerQueryRq returns excess ShipToAddress elements

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

Since the version 12.0 of the qbXML the CustomerQueryRq responce retains the ShipToAddress elements - these are the random set of addresses ever used in QuickBooks. On Screen reference says the responce can contain up to 50 shipping addresses, but in reality it returns all the shipping addresses ever used in QuickBooks and because I have more than 10000 addresses - it retrieves each customer several seconds and crashes when I try to retrieve multiple customers.

I tried to use elements filtering - IncludeRetElement with only necessary fields, but the ShipToAddress elements start to appear the same time I include ShipAddress element(not ShipToAddress) into the retrieval list.

Is there way to retrieve customers from QuickBooks with the Shipping address without ShipToAddress, using qbXml 12.0/13.0?

P.S. For now I just use qbXml 11.0 but I want to use the latest versions in future.

My sample query I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<CustomerQueryRq>
<FullName>Test Customer</FullName>
<IncludeRetElement>ShipAddress</IncludeRetElement>
</CustomerQueryRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: I have passed this along to development and they will look at why it is returning so many entries.